Pattern matching callback for plotly dash - python
I've got a dropdown that allows me to filter a categorical plotly graph. A separate callback allows the user to alter this graph from a bar chart to a pie chart. This part  works as expected.
I've got separate slider components that adjust the settings for both the bar chart or the pie chart. The problem is the sliders are fixed in place. Is it possible to add/remove the relevant sliders based on the selection chosen in the radio items?
If the bar chart is selected (see below), only the two bar sliders should be visible. The other two should be dropped or removed. Conversely, if the pie is chosen, to the opposite should occur. The bar sliders are removed in place of the pie sliders.
The layout on the filtering div should stay the same.
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Fruit': ['Apple','Banana','Orange','Kiwi','Lemon'],
   'Value': [1,2,4,8,6],
   })

external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

filter_box = html.Div(children=[

    html.Div(children=[

        html.Label('Fruit', style = {}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id = 'value_type',
            options = [
                {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df['Fruit'].unique()
            ],
            value = df['Fruit'].unique(),
            multi = True,
            clearable = True
        ),

        html.Label('Cat Chart', style = {'display': 'inline','paddingTop': '0rem', "justifyContent": "center"}),
        dcc.RadioItems(['Bar','Pie'],'Bar', 
                       id = 'catmap', 
                       ),

       html.Label('Bar Transp', style = {'display': 'inline-block', 'paddingTop': '0.1rem',}),
        dcc.Slider(0, 1, 0.2,
               value = 0.6,
               id = 'bar_transp'),

        html.Label('Bar Width', style = {'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Slider(200, 1000, 200,
               value = 600,
               id = 'bar_width'),

        html.Label('Pie Transp', style = {'display': 'inline-block', 'paddingTop': '0.1rem',}),
        dcc.Slider(0, 1, 0.2,
               value = 0.6,
               id = 'pie_transp'),

        html.Label('Pie Hole', style = {'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Slider(0, 1, 0.2,
               value = 0.4,
               id = 'pie_hole'),

    ], className = "vstack",            
    )
])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(html.Div(filter_box), 
                        ),
            ]),
        ]),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dcc.Graph(id = 'type-chart'),
            ]),
        ])
    ])
], fluid = True)

@app.callback(
    Output('type-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input('value_type', 'value'), 
     Input('catmap', 'value'), 
     Input('bar_transp', 'value'), 
     Input('bar_width', 'value'), 
     Input('pie_transp', 'value'), 
     Input('pie_hole', 'value'), 
    ])     

def chart(value_type, catmap, bar_transp, bar_width, pie_transp, pie_hole):

    dff = df[df['Fruit'].isin(value_type)]

    if catmap == 'Bar':

        df_count = dff.groupby(['Fruit'])['Value'].count().reset_index(name = 'counts')

        if df_count.empty == True:
            type_fig = go.Figure()

        else:
            df_count = df_count

            type_fig = px.bar(x = df_count['Fruit'], 
                      y = df_count['counts'],
                      color = df_count['Fruit'],
                      opacity = bar_transp,
                      width = bar_width
                      )

    elif catmap == 'Pie':

        df_count = dff.groupby(['Fruit'])['Value'].count().reset_index(name = 'counts')

        if df_count.empty == True:
            type_fig = go.Figure()

        else:
            df_count = df_count

            type_fig = px.pie(df_count,
                              values = df_count['counts'],
                              opacity = pie_transp,
                              hole = pie_hole
                             )

    return type_fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = True)



Pattern-matching callbacks are not needed in this situation, it could be though if the filters were to be created dynamically. Instead, in order to add/remove the relevant sliders based on the selected graph type, you would wrap them in a component (as children) and use a callback to update the children property of that component.
However, I suggest you just show/hide the sliders rather than add/remove them so that their state is preserved across graph type updates :

Use one wrapper component for each type (here 'filter_bar' and 'filter_pie') :
filter_box = html.Div(children=[

    html.Div(children=[

        html.Label('Fruit', style = {}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id = 'value_type',
            options = [
                {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df['Fruit'].unique()
            ],
            value = df['Fruit'].unique(),
            multi = True,
            clearable = True
        ),

        html.Label('Cat Chart', style = {'display': 'inline','paddingTop': '0rem', "justifyContent": "center"}),
        dcc.RadioItems(['Bar','Pie'],'Bar',
                    id = 'catmap',
                    ),

        html.Div(id='filter_bar', children=[
            html.Label('Bar Transp', style = {'display': 'inline-block', 'paddingTop': '0.1rem',}),
            dcc.Slider(0, 1, 0.2,
                value = 0.6,
                id = 'bar_transp'),

            html.Label('Bar Width', style = {'display': 'inline-block'}),
            dcc.Slider(200, 1000, 200,
                value = 600,
                id = 'bar_width'),
        ]),


        html.Div(id='filter_pie', children=[
            html.Label('Pie Transp', style = {'display': 'inline-block', 'paddingTop': '0.1rem',}),
            dcc.Slider(0, 1, 0.2,
                value = 0.6,
                id = 'pie_transp'),

            html.Label('Pie Hole', style = {'display': 'inline-block'}),
            dcc.Slider(0, 1, 0.2,
                value = 0.4,
                id = 'pie_hole'),
        ])

    ], className = "vstack",
    )
])


And update its style property in a callback :
 @app.callback(
    Output('filter_bar', 'style'),
    Output('filter_pie', 'style'),
    Input('catmap', 'value')
)
def display_sliders(catmap):
    if catmap == 'Bar':
        return {}, {'display': 'none'}

    if catmap == 'Pie':
        return {'display': 'none'}, {}

    return {'display': 'none'}, {'display': 'none'}




Thank you. Very helpful. Do you have any links that explain in greater detail the difference between adding/removing and showing/hiding?

Not really, but let's take this example, where the set_display_children callback displays the selected country and city by adding/removing some text to the layout, as a children property of a specific container. In your case, this specific container would be for example html.Div(id='sliders'), placed just after the 'catmap' component, and in a callback you would update its children according to the catmap by returning the corresponding pair of components (label+sliders).

However now that I rethink about that, doing this would prevent the first callback to run : since the sliders are used as inputs of that callback, adding/removing those inputs from the layout would require to register the callback again with the new inputs after each update so that it can still be triggered.

Yeh I went through those examples, which gave me the approach of pattern matching but it didn't meet the exact requirements. Thanks for the info.
